# Выборка условно ограниченных данных из одной таблицы

Tags: запрос, mysql

Есть таблица вида:
**t_news**

- id
- title
- cat

Категории не последовательны для каждой новости. То есть, может быть сначала 2 новости 1-ой категории, потом одна 3-ей, затем одна 5-ой и т.д.

Задача

> **Нужно получить по 5 новостей каждой категории, отсортированных по дате.**

То, есть вывод должен быть приблизительно следующим (пример, по 3 новости, 3 категории):

```
id  title       cat
1   новость1    1
2   новость2    1
3   новость3    1
4   новость4    2
5   новость5    2
6   новость6    2
7   новость7    3
8   новость8    3
9   новость9    3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не дождавшись ответа, сам отвечаю:

```
SELECT id, title, category, from_unixtime(date) `date` FROM (
  SELECT id, title, category, `date`
  FROM
  (
    SELECT id, title, category, `date`, @r:=IF(@cat = category, @r+1, 1) AS RowNum , @cat:= category AS Cat2 
    FROM cf_text, (SELECT @cat:= 0) AS category, (SELECT @r:= 0) AS r
    WHERE menu=2 AND hide=0 AND category>0
    ORDER BY category, `date` DESC, id
  ) t
  WHERE RowNum <= 4 LIMIT 16
) t2 
ORDER BY `date` DESC;
```